# How to use different column as key for pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How can I use different column for key in pivot table for example by default he looks at id(increment). How to point it to another column. For example

Pivot table

```
$table->integer('slow_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('slow_id')->references('id')->on('slow')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->integer('fast_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('fast_id')->references('shift')->on('fast')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->primary(['slow_id', 'fast_id']);
```

First table

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->timestamps();
```

Second table

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('shift');
$table->string('name');
$table->timestamps();
```

Comment: what do you want to edit to, simply change the pivot table details and their links

Comment: Just rename you fast table's id column : use `$table->increments('shift')` instead of `$table->increments('id');` !

Comment: sorry I corrected it(instead gear I rename shift in the table). It constantly putting out error  (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
   incorrectly formed")

Comment: No remove this line `$table->integer('shift');` and this one `$table->increments('id');` and do like this instead `$table->increments(‌​'shift')`

Comment: can't that is connected to another table, this is the reason why I'm doing this second column

Comment: there is no problem i think you can refer the same column in as many table as you want update the other table definition to refer the new primary key `shift` and i forgot you must add `protected $primaryKey = 'shift';` to your `fast` Model